# How can I continuously add my If statement contents together

Tags: vb.net

The basicServiceFee allows for 10 free connections at $80

Anytime the connections are > 10 each addition connection is $4 plus the basic

How can I add the $4 charge and keep adding it when each number from the connectionsListBox is selected.

My code adds the first $4 charge and then stops after 11 on the connectionsListBox.  How do I get 12 to be another $4 and 13 to be another $4

Here is my code:

```
Private Function businessTotalCharges(ByVal processingFee As Double, ByVal basicServiceFee As Double,
                                 ByVal premiumChannelFee As Double, ByVal connections As Double) As Double

    Dim total As Double
    Dim perchannel As Double
    Dim totalChannelFee As Double
    Dim connectionsPrice As Double
    Dim perConnection As Double

    processingFee = 16.5
    basicServiceFee = 80

    perchannel = CDbl(premiumListBox.SelectedItem) * 50
    connections = CDbl(connectionsListBox.SelectedItem)
    premiumChannelFee = (CDbl(premiumListBox.SelectedItem))

    If connections > 10 Then
        connectionsPrice = basicServiceFee + 4
    End If

    If connections <= 10 Then
        connectionsPrice = basicServiceFee
    End If

    If premiumChannelFee > 0 Then
        totalChannelFee = perchannel + connectionsPrice
    End If

    total = totalChannelFee + processingFee
    totalLabel.Text = total.ToString("C2")

    Return total
End Function


Private Sub calcButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles calcButton.Click

    Dim procFee As Double
    Dim basicFee As Double
    Dim channelFee As Double
    Dim connectionNum As Double

    If residentialRadioButton.Checked = True Then
        Call residentialTotalCharges(procFee, basicFee, channelFee)
    End If

    If businessRadioButton.Checked = True Then
        Call businessTotalCharges(procFee, basicFee, channelFee, connectionNum)
    End If

End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple math:

```
connectionsPrice = basicServiceFee + 4 * (connections - 10)
```

Comment: No need for the If/Then at all... this is right whether or not there are more than 10 connections or fewer.

Comment: Ugh can't believe I overlooked that.  Been doing homework all day my brain is fried.  Thank You for the help.